# Calculating $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{a+bk^2}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I want to calculate the following summation:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{a+bk^2}$$
Any hint how I can calculate this? Is there any kind of closed form for this summation?

Comment: A closed form is unlikely, but you can try and use Euler-MacLaurin Summation formula, which is beyond algebra-precalculus.

Comment: We know that $~\displaystyle\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{x^2+k^2}=\frac\pi x~\coth\pi x$. This can be deduced by differentiating the natural logarithm of Euler's infinite product formula for the sine function.

Comment: @Lucian Seems interesting, can you please explain more how obtain this?

Comment: See [Basel problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem).

Answer (score 3):

*Mathematica* gives this solution:

$\frac{-i \psi ^{(0)}\left(n-\frac{i \sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}\right)+i \psi
   ^{(0)}\left(n+\frac{i \sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}\right)+\frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a}}+\pi  \coth
   \left(\frac{\pi  \sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}\right)}{2 \sqrt{a} \sqrt{b}}$,

where $\psi$ is the *PolyGamma* function, strongly suggesting there is no deep insight to be gained otherwise.